# how can I concate jstl or EL value to form a complete attribute value

Tags: jsp, jstl, concatenation, el

I have <a href> tag in html
My model has a java list list1 as model attribute. I am trying to construct

<a href="pathvalue/namevalue">

```
<c:forEach var="obj" items="${list}">
  <a href="${obj.path}+"/"+${obj.name}".../>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to know how can I insert "/". I can directly concate two El value
${obj.path}${obj.name} but how to get that "/"

is below line correct to get a output  "pathvalue/namevalue"?

```
<c:out value="${obj.path+'/'+obj.name}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate it because "+" sign is used for arithmetic addition.

You should use

```
${obj.path}/${obj.name}
```

or do it in servlet to expose a bean property with already concatenated value.